# Use find_nearest function on PySpark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe in PySpark that has the following schema:

```
root
 |-- value: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp: long (nullable = true)
 |-- variable_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Intensity: float (nullable = true)
```

And the dataframe itself looks like this (I will just show the columns *value* and *intensity*, since they are the only ones I need for what I want to do):

| value | Intensity |
| --- | --- |
| [-0.01, 58] | 59 |
| [47.2, -20.1] | 30 |

What I would like to do is the following: take the value of the column *"Intensity"*, and look for the closest value to that one in the array of *"value"*. This value will be added to a new column, called *"nearest"*. So, in my example, I would get:

| value | Intensity | nearest |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [-0.01, 58] | 59 | 58 |
| [47.2, -20.1] | 30 | 47.2 |

To do this, I have tried the following:

- First, I defined my find_nearest function:

```
def find_nearest(array, value):
    array = np.array(array)
    nearest_index = np.where(abs(array - value) == abs(array - value).min())[0]
    nearest_value = array[abs(array - value) == abs(array - value).min()]
    return nearest_index[0] ## returns just the index of the nearest value
```

- Then, I try to use my function in my dataframe. I tried:

```
df2 = df.withColumn("nearest", [find_nearest(a, b) for a, b in zip(df['value'], df['Intensity'])])
```

But I get an error:

> TypeError: Column is not iterable

Could someone please give me a hand with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you get means you need to define an [UDF](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.udf.html).

However, here you can simply use Spark builtin functions. Here's one way using `transform` and `array_min` with structs ordering:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([([-0.01, 58.0], 59), ([47.2, -20.1], 30)], ["value", "Intensity"])

result = df.withColumn(
    "nearest",
    F.array_min(
        F.expr("transform(value, x -> struct(abs(x - Intensity), x as v))")
    )["v"]
)

result.show()

# +-------------+---------+-------+
# |        value|Intensity|nearest|
# +-------------+---------+-------+
# |[-0.01, 58.0]|       59|   58.0|
# |[47.2, -20.1]|       30|   47.2|
# +-------------+---------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it without creating custom function

```
>>> from pyspark.sql import functions as F
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame( [([-0.01, 58.0],59), ([47.2, -20.1],30)],['value', 'Intensity'])
>>> df1=df.withColumn("col1",df["value"].getItem(0)).withColumn("col2",df["value"].getItem(1))

>>> df1.withColumn("nearest",when(((df1["Intensity"] - F.abs(df1["col1"]))<(df1["Intensity"] - F.abs(df1["col2"]))),df1["col1"]).otherwise(df1["col2"])).drop(df1["col1"
+-------------+---------+-------+
|        value|Intensity|nearest|
+-------------+---------+-------+
|[-0.01, 58.0]|       59|   58.0|
|[47.2, -20.1]|       30|   47.2|
+-------------+---------+-------+
```

Comment: What if the array contains more than 2 values?